# Center a label vertically inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something I think is pretty easy but clearly making a pigs ears of it. Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/555581/)

I have a button and a label on display. I want to centre the label in the middle of the div, so horizontally and vertically centred.

I can centre it horizontally but not vertically. So I have tried a few things but nothing seems to centre the label vertically, even the vertical-align I use below. Not really sure why though?

```
.headerLbl {
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14pt; 
   display: block;
   vertical-align: central;
}
```

Comment: use padding-top: 50px for it. Adjust 50 to what every number you require.

Comment: Add `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the `.menu` class in CSS.

Comment: @David it centres it vertically but now not horizontally?

Comment: You can also add `justify-content: center` for horizontally centering.

Comment: ah I see but that then centres the button, i want the button to remain on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following styles into your code:

```
.menu {  
  background-color: #9FACEC;    /* Medium blue */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.headerLbl {
   align-self: center;
   width: 90%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

[image: It shouldn't. Notice the width with label.]

Comment: it centres it vertically but now not horizontally?

Comment: Updated the code, please check now

Comment: thanks, it now centres the label both vertically and horizontally but the button is now also centred, i want the button to remain on the left hand side

Comment: Please see above updates.

Comment: thanks, are you able to copy the link to your fiddle? I can't see the changes in the image you posted, cheers

Comment: sorry ignore my previous comment, now working thanks